# error al guardar Mysql query en array PHP

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax, php5

El problema es que cuando trato de guardar el query sql en un arreglo PHP para luego enviarlo como JSON, no se envia nada o se envia un solo registro. Les muestro el codigo.

```js
 $("#btn-send").click(()=>{
  var datos_to_send={data:"estados"}; //Esta informacion se recibe correctamente en el post del archivo PHP
    
  console.log("mostrando valor de texto "+datos_to_send.data);

  $.ajax({
   url:"js/link.php",
   type:"POST",
   dataType:"JSON",
   data:datos_to_send,
   async:false,
   beforesend:(something)=>{
    alert('Inicia AJAX');

   },
   success : (json)=> {
    alert('Exito! Funciona bien ');
   },
   error : (xhr, status)=> {
       alert('Disculpe, existió un problema');
       console.log("Error "+status);
       console.log("Error nro"+xhr);
   }, 
      complete : (xhr, status)=> {
          alert('Finaliza AJAX');
      }     
  }).done((recibido)=>{
   alert('Exitoooo'+recibido);
   console.log(recibido);
  })

 })
```

Este archivo JS al parecer funciona correctamente al hacer el envio de la informacion via POST.

```
<?php
    $data_received = $_POST["data"]; //Recibe bien la informacion
    $host="localhost";
    $port=3306;
    $user="root";
    $dbname="extras";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $dbname);
    if (!$conn) 
    {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM estados";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
  //Hasta este punto el codigo funciona correctamente

    $array_to_send=array(); 
    $i=0;

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {

            $array_to_send[$i] = $row; 
        //El problema se muestra en esta linea,
        //Si ejecuto el codigo asi no envia nada
        //Se muestra código 200 pero ninguna información
        //Simplemente envia NADA

            $i++;

        $array_to_send = $row; 
        //Pero si le quito los corchetes y el indice
        //De esta manera me envia correctamente 1 solo registro
        //Generalmente el ultimo
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
            echo json_encode("nada por aqui", JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
    echo json_encode($array_to_send);
    die();
?>
```

Como escribi en los comentarios, el codigo. No entiendo que sucede, la unica manera de que envie la informacion de manera "relativamente" correcta es que quite el indice de la variable que guarda los queries, pero son muchos los registros que debo enviar. ¿Alguien me puede explicar la manera correcta de enviar registros de PHP a JS en un arreglo?

Muchas gracias de antemano

Luego de pintar el resultado del arreglo con `print_r($array_to_send);`se muestra lo siguiente

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [id_estado] => 1
            [1] => Amazonas
            [estado] => Amazonas
            [2] => VE-X
            [iso_3166-2] => VE-X
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [id_estado] => 2
            [1] => Anzo�tegui
            [estado] => Anzo�tegui
            [2] => VE-B
            [iso_3166-2] => VE-B
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [id_estado] => 3
            [1] => Apure
            [estado] => Apure
            [2] => VE-C
            [iso_3166-2] => VE-C
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [id_estado] => 4
            [1] => Aragua
            [estado] => Aragua
            [2] => VE-D
            [iso_3166-2] => VE-D
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [id_estado] => 5
            [1] => Barinas
            [estado] => Barinas
            [2] => VE-E
            [iso_3166-2] => VE-E
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [id_estado] => 6
            [1] => Bol�var
            [estado] => Bol�var
            [2] => VE-F
            [iso_3166-2] => VE-F
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [id_estado] => 7
            [1] => Carabobo
            [estado] => Carabobo
            [2] => VE-G
            [iso_3166-2] => VE-G
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [id_estado] => 8
            [1] => Cojedes
            [estado] => Cojedes
            [2] => VE-H
            [iso_3166-2] => VE-H
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
            [id_estado] => 9
            [1] => Delta Amacuro
            [estado] => Delta Amacuro
            [2] => VE-Y
            [iso_3166-2] => VE-Y
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [id_estado] => 10
            [1] => Falc�n
            [estado] => Falc�n
            [2] => VE-I
            [iso_3166-2] => VE-I
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11
            [id_estado] => 11
            [1] => Gu�rico
            [estado] => Gu�rico
            [2] => VE-J
            [iso_3166-2] => VE-J
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [id_estado] => 12
            [1] => Lara
            [estado] => Lara
            [2] => VE-K
            [iso_3166-2] => VE-K
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [0] => 13
            [id_estado] => 13
            [1] => M�rida
            [estado] => M�rida
            [2] => VE-L
            [iso_3166-2] => VE-L
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [0] => 14
            [id_estado] => 14
            [1] => Miranda
            [estado] => Miranda
            [2] => VE-M
            [iso_3166-2] => VE-M
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [0] => 15
            [id_estado] => 15
            [1] => Monagas
            [estado] => Monagas
            [2] => VE-N
            [iso_3166-2] => VE-N
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [0] => 16
            [id_estado] => 16
            [1] => Nueva Esparta
            [estado] => Nueva Esparta
            [2] => VE-O
            [iso_3166-2] => VE-O
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [0] => 17
            [id_estado] => 17
            [1] => Portuguesa
            [estado] => Portuguesa
            [2] => VE-P
            [iso_3166-2] => VE-P
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [0] => 18
            [id_estado] => 18
            [1] => Sucre
            [estado] => Sucre
            [2] => VE-R
            [iso_3166-2] => VE-R
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19
            [id_estado] => 19
            [1] => T�chira
            [estado] => T�chira
            [2] => VE-S
            [iso_3166-2] => VE-S
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20
            [id_estado] => 20
            [1] => Trujillo
            [estado] => Trujillo
            [2] => VE-T
            [iso_3166-2] => VE-T
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [0] => 21
            [id_estado] => 21
            [1] => Vargas
            [estado] => Vargas
            [2] => VE-W
            [iso_3166-2] => VE-W
        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [0] => 22
            [id_estado] => 22
            [1] => Yaracuy
            [estado] => Yaracuy
            [2] => VE-U
            [iso_3166-2] => VE-U
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [0] => 23
            [id_estado] => 23
            [1] => Zulia
            [estado] => Zulia
            [2] => VE-V
            [iso_3166-2] => VE-V
        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [0] => 24
            [id_estado] => 24
            [1] => Distrito Capital
            [estado] => Distrito Capital
            [2] => VE-A
            [iso_3166-2] => VE-A
        )

    [24] => Array
        (
            [0] => 25
            [id_estado] => 25
            [1] => Dependencias Federales
            [estado] => Dependencias Federales
            [2] => VE-Z
            [iso_3166-2] => VE-Z
        )

)
```

este es el arreglo que quiero que se envie al archivo JS, pero de igual manera al ejecutar la accion click, me muestra un mensaje de error "parsererror" y entra en la funcion de error de ajax y no en la de success.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Según los ejemplos se debe acceder al elemento indice de la fila, en este caso 

$array_to_send[] =  $row['nombre_campo'];

O tu intención e vaciar toda la fila en llenado de tu array_to_send ?

Comment: Correcto, quiero vaciar toda la fila dentro de array_to_send... Es lo que estoy intentando, mi unica pista es "parseerror" que es el texto de error que me arroja el archivo al fallar...

Comment: antes del cierre de conexion puedes pintar el arreglo ?

print_r($array_to_send);
die;

Para ver que contiene ?

Comment: Si por supuesto... Lo acabo de hacer... El arreglo se muestra correctamente estructurado, pero igual arroja un mensaje de error. En la funcion ajax no entra en la funcion de success, sino en la funcion de error... Ya agrego el resultado de print_r($array_to_send); en el codigo del post

Comment: por lo que veo la estructura esta correcta, lo que podría ser, es que los caracteres especiales que están en tu array este provocando el problema de json_encode, podrías intentar codificarlos o  saltarlos, por que segun lo que indicabas solo te muestra un resultado positivo cuando muestras el ultimo array del ciclo, y por lo que veo ese ultimo array no contiene caracteres especiales..

Atento a tus comentarios.
Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas indicar el indice del array.  Intentalo de esta forma:

```
$array_to_send=array(); 

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {

        $array_to_send[] = $row; 

    }
}
```

Comment: Ya lo intente de esa manera y no funciona... sucede lo mismo.. error

Comment: cual es el error

Comment: En el código explico el problema con comentarios mas detallados...

Answer (score 0):

Listo! Consegui la respuesta, no se por que, pero la solucion fue eliminar la linea de dataType en la funcion ajax. Quedando de esta manera.

```
    $("#btn-send").click(()=>{
    var datos_to_send={data:"estados"};
    console.log("mostrando valor de texto "+datos_to_send.data);

    $.ajax({
        url:"js/link.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:datos_to_send,
        async:false,
        beforesend:(something)=>{
            alert('Inicia AJAX');

        },
        success : (response)=> {
            alert('Exito! Funciona bien ');
        },
        error : (xhr, status)=> {
            alert('Disculpe, existió un problema');
            console.log("Error "+status);
            console.log(xhr);
        },  
        complete : (xhr, status)=> {
            alert('Finaliza AJAX');
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log("complete: "+status);
        }                   
    }).done((recibido)=>{
        alert('Exitoooo'+recibido);
        console.log(recibido);
    })

})
```

Y el archivo link.php queda asi

```
    $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $dbname);
if (!$conn) 
{
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


$sql = "SELECT * FROM estados";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($con));

$array_to_send=[];
$i=0;

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        //array_push($array_to_send, $row);
        $array_to_send[] = $row;
        $i++;
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
} 
else 
{
        echo json_encode("nada por aqui", JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
}
print_r($array_to_send);
echo json_encode($array_to_send);
mysqli_close($conn);
die();
```

De igual manera muchas gracias a los que se tomaron la molestia de leer mi codigo y ayudarme.